# Use Q object and Paginator together in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, paginator

I've created View which filters data by search query given in textbox. As well as I used Paginator to show data divided into pages.

My problem is, when I filter data with Q object then and try to paginate by clicking the next button, all data is refreshed.

When I search text by Q object the URL becomes http://127.0.0.1:8000/mael/parties/?q=keyword

And from clicking the next button the URL becomes http://127.0.0.1:8000/mael/parties/?page=2

When I manually change URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/mael/parties/?q=keyword&page=2, then it works. But I don't know how to do this in code.

**Is it possible to use Q object search and pagination together?**

My View

```
from mael.models import PartyTotalBillsView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class PartyListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    model = PartyTotalBillsView

def parties(request):
    # Show all records or searched query record    
    search_text = request.GET.get('q','')   

    try:
        if search_text:
            queryset = (Q(party_name__icontains=search_text))
            party_list = PartyTotalBillsView.objects.filter(queryset).order_by('party_name')
        else:
            # Show all data if empty keyword is entered
            party_list = PartyTotalBillsView.objects.order_by('party_name')
    except PartyTotalBillsView.DoesNotExist:
        party_list = None
    
    paginator = Paginator(party_list, 2) # Show 2 rows per page: for Test
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    
    party_list = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    
    return render(request, 'mael/parties.html', {'party_list': party_list})
```

Template file

```
<form id="search-form" method="get" action="/mael/parties/">
    <input id="search-text" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter search keyword">
    <input class="btn-search-party" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>        
<br/>


<table class="show-data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Party Name</th>
        <th>Total Bill Amount</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    {% if party_list %}
    <tbody>
    {% for party in party_list %}
        <tr>
        <td class="party-id">{{ party.party_id }}</td>
        <td class="party-name">{{ party.party_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ party.total_bills }}</td>
        <td class="party-phone">{{ party.party_phone }}</td>
        <td class="party-address">{{ party.party_address }}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn-modify" data-partyid="{{party.party_id}}" type="buttton">
            Modify
            </button>
        </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    {% endif %}
</table>


<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
    {% if party_list.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ party_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ party_list.number }} of {{ party_list.paginator.num_pages }}
    </span>

    {% if party_list.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ party_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        <a href="?page={{ party_list.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have two views? A CBV and a FBV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do *not* use two views. A `ListView` can perform filtering as well:

```
class PartyListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    model = PartyTotalBillsView
    template_name = 'mael/parties.html'
    context_object_name = 'party_list'

    def querystring(self):
        qs = self.request.GET.copy()
        qs.pop(self.page_kwarg, None)
        return qs.urlencode()

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if 'q' in self.request.GET:
            qs = qs.filter(party_name__icontains=self.request.GET['q'])
        return qs.order_by('party_name')
```

In the links for the previous and next pages, you then append the `querystring` of the view:

```
    <span class="step-links">
    {% if party_list.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1&amp;{{ view.querystring }}">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&amp;{{ view.querystring }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
    </span>

    {% if party_list.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&amp;{{ view.querystring }}">next</a>
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}&amp;{{ view.querystring }}">last &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
    </span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Django since last month so was no idea about CBV and FBV. But found Class-Based View looks cleaner. class PartyListView(ListView) was copy-paste from other code and had no effect in this app. But this mistake gets me an idea of beautiful CBV.

Answer (score 1):

### Pagination & CBV

If you are using django generic ListView with paginate_by attribute, you don't need to build paginator instance. Either you use CBV (Class Based View) or Function Views but not both.

For HTML display create a `_django_pager.html` page to include in your list pages.

```html
{% comment %}
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/
{% endcomment %}

{% if is_paginated %}

  <ul class="pagination">

    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}

      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page=page_obj.previous_page_number %}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><a href="#" class="page-link">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">{{ i }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page=i %}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}


    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page=page_obj.next_page_number %}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><a href="#" class="page-link">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>

{% endif %}
```

### Filtering

Q object is powerfull for building complex query but you have to **specify DB field under which Q object applies**.

Instead of hardcoding the form in HTML I recommand to use a Form Class. So in `forms.py` create a PartySearchForm

```py
class PartySearchForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Search in party
    """
    search_text = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                          required=False,
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                              "class": "form-control",
                              "placeholder": "Search"
                              })
                          )
```

#### Option 1: filter queryset in view

```py
class PartyListView(ListView):
    model = PartyTotalBillsView
    form = PartySearchForm
    paginate_by = 100

    def build_where(self):
        where = Q(pk__gt=0)
        if self.request.GET.get("search_text"):
            search_list = self.request.GET.get("search_text", None).split()
            for search_item in search_list:
                where &= (
                    Q(party_name__icontains=search_item)
                )
        return where

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        qswhere = qs.filter(self.build_where())
        # first param must be request.GET or None (essential for the first load and initial values)
        # https://www.peterbe.com/plog/initial-values-bound-django-form-rendered
        self.form = PartySearchForm(self.request.GET or None)
        return qswhere
```

In the `build_where` function you can add as many search field as you want. You can search on other DB field than party_name by adding the fields to the where variable.

```py
where &= (
    Q(party_name__icontains=search_item)
    | Q(party_location__icontains=search_item)
)
```

You can also add other search fields than `search_text` in your form and add Q search on the where variable.

```py
if self.request.GET.get("my_new_field"):
   where &= Q(supplier=self.request.GET.get("my_new_field", ""))
```

Key point here is the `get_queryset` method where the displayed queryset is defined, ie: fetched, filtered and sorted (which could also be a method). `.order_by('party_name')` is not useful if you add a class Meta in `models.py`

```py
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Let's go party"
        ordering = ['party_name']
```

One other way to do would be to pass the queryset to the form and perform the search

#### Option 2: filter queryset in form

Looks even cleaner with the search logic in the SearchForm only!

`PartyListView.get_queryset` become

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs1 = self.model.objects.all()
        self.form = PartySearchForm(self.request.GET, queryset=qs1)
        qs = self.form.get_queryset(self.request.GET)
        return qs
```

`PartySearchForm` become

```py
class PartySearchForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Search in party
    """
    search_text = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                          required=False,
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                              "class": "form-control",
                              "placeholder": "Search"
                              })
                          )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Takes an option named argument ``queryset`` as the base queryset used in
        the ``get_queryset`` method.
        """
        self.queryset = kwargs.pop("queryset", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        where = Q(pk__gt=0)
        # is_valid() check is important to get access to cleaned_data
        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.queryset
        search_text = self.cleaned_data.get("search_text").strip()
        if search_text:
            search_list = search_text.split()
            for search_item in search_list:
                where &= (
                    Q(party_name__icontains=search_item)
                )
        qs = self.queryset.filter(where)
        return qs.distinct()
```

Eventually, if you are using Postgres DB and want to go deeper with Text Search you can implement [Django full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/). Pros & cons can be gained by reading [this](https://pauloxnet.medium.com/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql-4e3584dee4ae).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement this code but clicking the search button has no effect. Maybe I need to connect the button to View/Form. Sorry for such a silly question. I am a just-month-old Django learner and trying to convert one of my desktop-based app to a web app.

Comment: You have to remove the action from the <form> tag
Here is how to rewrite your form html code:
<form id="search-form" method="get">
  {{view.form.search_text}}
  <input class="btn-search-party" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

Comment: Once submitted you should pass through get_queryset method of the ListView with an access to self.request.GET.  In fact it pass through the get method. If you look at the ancestor of ListView (BaseListView) you'll see the get method calling the get_queryset(). Try to print 'self.request.GET' out in get_queryset. You should see an output like: <QueryDict: {'search_text': ['my search string']}>